# How to get product finder collection on the catalog search page using search keyword in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, sql

I want to get the collection of Product Finder data

> (make, model, series, sku)

from product finder admin grid based on search keyword.

For now, Products and categories are searched using the keyword, but I don't know how to display the data from product finder on the basis of the search keyword.

If anyone has Idea, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the collection using join the tables:

```
<?php 

    $collection = Mage::getModel('amfinder/value')->getCollection();

    $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true)->joinLeft(array('am_finder_map'), "am_finder_map.value_id = main_table.value_id", array('sku'=> 'am_finder_map.sku','pid'=> 'am_finder_map.pid'))->group('main_table.value_id');
    $collection->getSelect()->distinct(true)->joinLeft(array('am_finder_dropdown'), "am_finder_dropdown.dropdown_id = main_table.dropdown_id", array('keyname'=> 'am_finder_dropdown.name','dropdown_id'=> 'am_finder_dropdown.dropdown_id'))->group('main_table.value_id');

?>
```